# How to get the original Height of a HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a div:

```
<div id="div" style="height:150px; border:solid thin blue;"></div>
```

is there a way to retrieve the **original** div height? The div is resizable, so the user may have resized it before my code loads.
Note: my code is a jQuery plugin, so I have no clue about what happened to the element before my plugin is called (so please don't tell me to store height in element data...)

[jqFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dDjeQ/1/) in this demo, I want to get the **150** after resizing the div.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because `resizable()` method override inline style `height` value.

You need to store it somewhere else.

For example before making `div` resizable:

```
var originalHeight = $('#div').height();
$('#div').resizable();

$('#cmd').button().click(function(){
    alert(originalHeight);
});
```

Comment: I cannot, is not me who initialize the elements, my plugin may be called after other plugins executed..

Comment: So, as I said, you can't. There is no such thing as history of changes in element.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is technically helpful! At least I have to find another way to solve my issue. I had 3 answers teaching me how to set size, how to store size in data!!!! WTF!!!!! Thanks anyway

Comment: @skafandri: You may rewrite your plugin so that its initialisation is apart from the execution. Like `$(...).plugin("init");` then do "something" you don't know, then call `$(...).plugin("reset");`

Comment: I'm trying to approach my problem another way, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552382/find-out-if-html-height-is-set-by-style-or-by-contnet

Answer (score 0):

```
originalHeight=0;
$(document).ready(function()
{
    originalHeight= $("#div").height()
});
```

Comment: While the code speaks for itself, the intention behind the code could use a little description. Why would you employ this technique? How is it specifically helpful to the question at hand? I think this answer has the most merit to it and will gladly upvote it if you provide an edit with this information.

Comment: I don't understand the problem of resizing dvi before loading code. This code will get original height after document is loaded(or I can bind this logic on div load event).My apologies if i didn't understand problem well

Comment: Oh I think you have the problem understood. The code you've presented here matches the accepted answer. What I think you've omitted that would have made this a better answer is the description of *why* this should work.

Comment: Yes it does, but the intention behind it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to get old data from the DOM, but could you not insist on the plugin having an init function called and get the values then? You could also advise in your documentation that the elements not be moved until you've completed the init function, although if it's called via .ready() this should occur before the user has a chance to blink anyway.

How is the div resizable, using jquery-ui?

Another option might be to get the page again using ajax and then parse the page, but it would be **a lot** of effort and very messy.

Comment: I'm trying to approach my problem another way, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552382/find-out-if-html-height-is-set-by-style-or-by-contnet