# Find out if HTML height is set by style or by content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have 2 divs:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>​
```

in my css:

```
#div1{ height:20px}​
```

Both divs have 20px height, check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ayUsw/1/)
How can I find out if the div have it's height due to content or have been set in css or inline style?
This helps me find out the dimensions have been set by the **developer** or just calculated by the browser.

Comment: I'm curious, why would you need to know programatically where the attribute was being set from?

Comment: If the height have been set with css or an inline style, then my plugin don't have the right to override it, otherwise I can override it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a way to achieve it :)

```
function getRealHeight(element){
    var height=0;
    if (element.children().length>0){
        var temp = $('<div></div>');
        temp.append(element.children());
        height = element.height();
        element.append(temp.children());
    } else {
        var html=element.html();
        element.html('');
        height = element.height();
        element.html(html);
    }
    return height;
}
```

​

​[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ayUsw/10/)

Comment: +1 nice trick. but what if I had an empty div? `.html()` won't return empty.

Comment: @skafandri i meant an empty div inside the element

Comment: DOM-serialization is not a good solution. During the DOM -> string -> DOM transformation process, certain data will be lost. (Just like with digital -> analog -> digital.)

Comment: Can you develop please? which kind of data may be lost?

Comment: @skafandri Read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392930/why-should-y-innerhtml-x-innerhtml-be-avoided), **especially** the accepted answer.

Comment: @skafandri That's the correct way to do it. I have also provided my own answer, check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Use this function:

```
function emptyHeight ( elem ) {
    var $temp = $( '<div />' );
    var $elem = $( elem );
    var height;

    $temp.append( $elem.contents() );
    height = $elem.height();
    $elem.append( $temp.contents() );

    return height;   
}
```

The idea is to temporarily detach all child nodes from the element. An element with no children has a height of `0`, *unless* its height is set via CSS.

Pass your DIV element into that function. If it returns `0`, that means that the DIV does *not* have its height set via CSS.

```
if ( emptyHeight( yourDiv ) === 0 ) {
    // the DIV does not have any height value set via CSS
} else {
    // the DIV has a CSS height set
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to search for the CSS height value and compare that?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="div-styled" style="height: 20px"></div>
<div id="div-unstyled"></div>
```

Check for ***inline*** CSS `height` property with plain JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('div-styled').style.height // "20px"
document.getElementById('div-unstyled').style.height.length // 0
```

---

**Update**

jQuery returns style rules from external style sheets as well with `.css()`

```js
var $el = $('#container');
$el.html( $el.css('height') );
```

```css
#container {
  height: 42px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Tried it in my case (external css sheet) returns '' in both cases.. http://jsfiddle.net/ayUsw/3/

Comment: doesn't cover external css or width/height attributes

Comment: @GeorgiiIvankin Correct. Only checks for *inline CSS height*